# Unable to auto-generate migrations using alembic

Tags: sqlalchemy, pyramid, alembic

My repository can be found here http://goo.gl/Q4WJXy (versions inside alembic folder)and I tried to use autogenerate migrations,

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "some message"
```

there is nothing related to creation of table i.e empty downgrade and upgrade functions. I configured my local database properly. How can i solve this?

My log looks like this

```
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl MySQLImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
  Target database is not up to date.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you executed `alembic upgrade head` first? Because it obviously cannot compare to an out-of-date database. Furthermore, you probably want to remove your MySQL root password (if it is the real one) from the repository code.

Comment: `upgrade` and `downgrade` are commands any user would execute when he upgrades your application. `revision` is a developer command - only you use it when you alter the schema. The short answer is **yes** but maybe you should read up on the documentation to wrap around htis idea. You should always work with an up to date schema and you need to understand alembic at least this far to work properly with it.

Comment: I had this issue when I had multiple version in alembic_version. When I delete the rows that did not correspond to the version of the database I was in (head in my case), I could auto generate the next revision.

Answer (score 4):

Basically Alembic compares your current database to your model and then generates the migration to get you database to be like your model.

I thought initially that the migrations is comparing latest revision with model, but actually it seems to ignore your revision file contents and is only looking to see if your database has the lates Alembic revision migration number.

So simply created the Alembic table and pasted the head revision number into it, in order for the migration to run and output the migration script I was looking for.
Alternatively you upgrade your database properly to the latest revision using Alembic and then create the new migration.

```
alembic upgrade head

alembic revision --autogenerate -m 'test revision'
```